# In the Twilight series, can a vampire impregnate a person?

Tags: twilight

I am often riddled by this question when I'm reading books about vampires. It also occurs when I'm watching a movie about vampires too.

**Can a vampire impregnate a human in *Twilight*?**

Comment: Only if the vampire is smoking hot and sparkles in the sun. Otherwise, no.

Comment: But I’d limit this question to *Twilight*, if I were you (is that what you meant by the tag?) It’s a little broad for fiction in general. It has a really easy answer in *Twilight*, too.

Comment: Different canons have different kinds of vampires. It's like asking if space aliens are allergic to green rocks.

Comment: I've edited your question to be only about *Twilight* since that's what you tagged it with, and it would otherwise be closed. If that's not what you meant, please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is a firm **yes**.

> Everything inside me came undone as I stared at the tiny porcelain face of the half-vampire, half-human baby.
>   <sub>Twilight, Breaking Dawn</sub>

And from the film of Bella pregnant with Edward's baby.

Comment: How is babby formed? How vampire get pragnent?

Answer (score 0):

As evidence by the fourth book, yes, vampires in twilight can impregnate a human. typically it doesn't happen, as most* vampires would lose control and end up draining said human of blood during the interaction, or break them. This can only happen in Male vampire with female human relationships, as a female vampire is in stasis, and no longer has monthly fluctuations, whereas a male vampire, it seems, still has reproductive ability.